# Inject scoped class to viewmodel of a fragment

Tags: android, dependency-injection, koin, koin-scope

I have this particular test case that I don't know how to solve with Koin.

I have a `FooClass` tied to the `MainActivity` lifecycle, and I have other fragments that also need to use `FooClass`. Those fragments need the `FooClass` to be inject in the viewmodels. (I don't want to declare `FooClass` as `single`)

I tried

```
    scope<MainActivity>{
        scoped { FooClass() }
        viewModel { FragmentSimpleViewModel(get()) }
    }
```

How can I do this?